# jQuery doesn't trigger function on window resize

Tags: jquery, window-resize

I've a bit of a strange situation. The script I created works great but not always.

**The background**

- I'm changing the default values of sliders of the YOP POLL plugin for WordPress.
  The sliders are in my example a 5 scale with numbers as their values, with on top labels to show to the users. The default value I set the sliders to is 3 or the middle one.

**What works?**

- On desktop browsers it all works well. The page gets loaded and the defaults are set to the middle answer.

**What works buggy / not?**

- On desktop browsers: when I resize the window the set values get lost and fall back to value 1 (the left one).
- On mobile browsers: (only tested with Chrome mobile on Android as I don't have any other mobile devices) I see the sliders being set to the middle value (3) and when the page is fully loaded they fall back to the left one (1). This also happens when they stay on the middle one, and when you then start to scroll down.

If been trying many suggestions regarding window resize in jQuery already but none seems to be the solution so far, unfortunately.

The simplified code is:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  function set_slider_defaults() {
    // the code to set the new defaults in the sliders
    console.log("Resize", new Date())
  };

  set_slider_defaults();
  $(window).resize(set_slider_defaults); // <-- this doesn't fire the set_slider_defaults function on window resize... why?!
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It seems that the set_slider_defaults call is not being triggered on the window resize event. How come?

When I change it into:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  console.log("window resized");
  set_slider_defaults();
});
```

Then I do see the "window resized" messages in the console logs pop up but the set_slider_defaults function is not trigger...

Anyone any suggestion what I'm overlooking here?

Comment: The code you have included should work, what makes you think it's not being called? Is it possible that there is actually something not working as expected inside `set_slider_defaults()`?

Comment: Your code works as you can see in the snippet I made you

Comment: Thanks guys, that at least gives me the feeling that I don't have to loose my mind today :)  I guess I'll have to do some further digging into the javascript code of the plugin then, perhaps I'm conflicting with an event in that piece of code... I'll have a fun evening checking that.

Comment: And @mplungjan thanks for adjusting the code. Will remember to do it like that in a next question.

Comment: Took a little longer to get it solved. It was indeed a conflict with the javascript of the plugin itself. I ended up contacting the plugin creator and together we got it solved. I'll post the solution as the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up contacting the plugin author and we got it working as my original code was conflicting with the plugin code.

The solution is really nice and short as it now utilizes the plugins own code. Just use the following to set the default value for the text-slider questions to the 3rd option:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
    $( '.basic-yop-poll-container .basic-question[data-question-type="text-slider"]' ).find( 'input[type="text"]' ).yopPollSlider( 'setValue', 3) ;
});
```